# Hibernate save multiple related objects in same transaction on at a time

Tags: hibernate

I am saving multiple related objects in one transaction one at time and I am looking for away to prevent `ConstraintViolationException` when I save a child object.

Code would look like this.

```
try{
    //with given session
    session.getTransaction().begin();
    session.save(objectA);
    objectB.setObjectA(objectA);
    //do something with object B before save
    session.save(objectB);
    if(!objectB.getObjectCSet().isEmpty()){
        for(ObjectC objectC:objectB.getObjectCSet){
             objectC.setObjectB(objectB);
             //do something with object C before saving
            session.save(objectC);
        }
    }
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}catch(Exception e){
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
}finally{
    if(session != null){
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

If I am not mistaken I could just use cascade and do something like `session.save(objectA);` with configuration of `cascade="save"`. I don't know how hibernate handle cascade but I would like to know if it does something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are entity associations between ObjectA to ObjectB and ObjectB to ObjectC, you can use `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` when you define the entity associations using @OneToMany etc.